# Confused about send method to set instance variables

Tags: ruby

I have the following code:

```
class Dog
  def initialize(attributes = {})
    attributes.each do |attr, value|
      send("#{attr}", value)
    end
  end
end


dog = Dog.new({:talk => 'bruuuf'})
```

And I get an  block in initialize': undefined method `talk' for # (NoMethodError)

Isn't send supposed to be doing something like:

`dog.talk = bruuuf` Why is not letting me do so? Also, this would not set an instance variable, but it would create an instance method. Right?

Comment: I'm not sure why you would use the `send` method to set instance variables in the first place, besides educational purpose or feeling adventurous.

Comment: completely educational purposes. And isn't send used to do that? I've seen send("@#{key}", value)

Comment: WHy somebody thinks this should be closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off: you cannot set instance variables with [`Object#send`](http://Ruby-Doc.Org/core-2.1.0/Object.html#method-i-send). `Object#send` sends messages, it doesn't set instance variables. Of course, you can send a message which may or may not then in turn invoke a method which may or may not in turn then set an instance variable, but that's not the doing of `Object#send`, it's the doing of whatever method was invoked in response to the message you sent.

If you want to dynamically set instance variables, use [`Object#instance_variable_set`](http://Ruby-Doc.Org/core-2.1.0/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_set):

```
class Dog
  def initialize(**attrs)
    attrs.each do |attr, value|
      instance_variable_set(:"@#{attr}", value)
    end
  end
end

dog = Dog.new(talk: 'bruuuf')
```

In this case, however, it looks like you don't actually want to set an instance variable but rather call a setter method. Setter methods have names that end with an `=` sign, e.g. `Dog#talk=`:

```
class Dog
  def initialize(**attrs)
    attrs.each do |attr, value|
      send(:"#{attr}=", value)
    end
  end
end

dog = Dog.new(talk: 'bruuuf')
```

Note, of course, that this assumes that the method `Dog#talk=` actually exists. If it doesn't, you will get a `NoMethodError`.

Comment: Awesome. I have just a couple of questions: Why (**) instead of just (*) in the arguments, and also, why writting ```:"#{attr}="``` instead of ```"#{attr}"```

Comment: 1) Keyword arguments are new in Ruby 2.0, they just are a good fit for this particular use case. 2) `send` takes both `Symbol`s and `String`s, but again, `Symbol` is just a good fit for this particular data type.

Answer (score 1):

Provided that method `talk` is defined, you can do `send(:talk)`, but since `talk` is not defined, you cannot do that. Furthermore, `dog.send(:talk)` will not give you `dog.talk = bruuuf`. Provided that `talk=` is defined, `dog.send(:talk=, ...)` will do it.

Comment: So, is this used to set instance variables usually?

Comment: sawa, but the typical ```attributes.each do |attr, value| self.send("#{attr}=", value) end```  in an initialize method is used to send values to a setter that usually set instance variables, right?

Comment: No. Setter methods are usually defined through `attr_setter`.

Comment: @sawa This pattern is e.g. used in Rails to set attributes passed in the initializer to the model object (which then more or less just sets instance variables). Using this pattern instead of directly setting the instance variables allows users (i.e. child classes) to override the setter and to introduce new behavior. Depending on the actual use-case of the OP, this might be too much indirection though...